# nginx on Windows: DeleteFile() failed error 15100 makes error log huge in size

Tags: nginx, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2016

we are running two nginx servers: v1.16.0 and v1.15.3 on windows as a buffering servers for static files on our actual Apache server. One runs at Windows Sever 2008 R2 and the other one on Windows Server 2016 Standard.

The log level was set to crit, to not bloat the logs. However lately we are experiencing some problems that cause the logs on both servers to go huge in size over days (>60gb) causing the whole server to stop working properly.

There isn't anything other in the logs than this:

```
[crit] 20476#19808: DeleteFile(): "C:\nginx/temp/cache/7/d1/32c220332caaac942c76e31d3fc1bd17.00000000043.DELETE" failed (5: FormatMessage() error:(15100))
[crit] 8340#3364: DeleteFile(): "C:\nginx/temp/cache/7/d1/32c220332caaac942c76e31d3fc1bd17.00000000043.DELETE" failed (5: FormatMessage() error:(15100))
[crit] 20476#19808: DeleteFile(): "C:\nginx/temp/cache/7/d1/32c220332caaac942c76e31d3fc1bd17" failed (5: FormatMessage() error:(15105))
```

This is the configuration of one of the servers:

```
worker_processes 1;
error_log logs/erorr.log crit;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log off;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 64;
    proxy_cache_path temp/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:60m max_size=1G;

    server {
        listen 81;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_in_redirect on;
            proxy_pass http://ourapacheserver
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
            proxy_cache_revalidate on;
            proxy_cache cache;
            proxy_cache_key $host$uri$request_filename$arg_file;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 990m;
            expires 9990;
            proxy_connect_timeout 600;
            proxy_send_timeout 600;
            proxy_read_timeout 600;
            proxy_cache_bypass 0;
            proxy_no_cache 0; 
        }
    }
}
```

What can cause these files to be "undeletable"? I couldn't find anything related to this problem.

Comment: Do these files/directories exist? Is something else "cleaning up" the cache?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot check it atm because I needed to clear something from the drive to be able to read the log file, so I choose to delete the cache. Nothing else should be cleaning the  cache, but I just noticed that a situation might happened that nginx was launched multiple times (so cache was cleared multiple times?). I re-configured some stuff and will need to monitor it.

Comment: If you have multiple instances running and one instance removes files from the other, this might be the culprit, yes. Either that or permissions configured in a way that nginx is not allowed to delete files it has created.